# Android WebView.LoadData doesn't work reliably with inputs created at runtime

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to code an Android program, and I'm running into a slightly strange problem that I'm not sure of the cause of: WebView.LoadData seems to behave rather unreliably if I'm asking it to load a string created by another function at runtime (at least, I'm assuming that that's the reason for the error - for all I know, it might be something completely different!).

A brief background for the code: I have a set of competitors who have a name, a colour, and a set of scores, and I want to make a leaderboard which changes as the code 'replays' the competition in question.  The code I'm using is as follows (apologies for any formatting errors; I've never used this site before):

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    leaderboard="";
    leaderboardWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    leaderboardWebView.loadData(leaderboard,"text/html",null);
    if (step < maxArraySize) {
      step = step+1;
      Collections.sort(myArray, new myObjectComparator());
      leaderboard="<html><body><b>";
      for (int i=0;i<myArray.size();i++) {
        leaderboard = leaderboard+"<font color='#"+Integer.toHexString(myArray.get(i).getDisplayColour())+"'>"+myArray.get(i).getName()+"</font>";
        if(i<myArray.size()-1) {leaderboard=leaderboard+" - ";}
      }
        leaderboard = leaderboard+"</b></body></html>";
        leaderboardWebView.loadData(leaderboard,"text/html","UTF-8");
      }
    handler.postDelayed(this,period);
  }
};
```

Using the Android Studio debugger, I've confirmed that the sorting and concatenation portions do what I want to, so the leaderboard html comes out as I expect.

However, the LoadData method doesn't seem to work all the time.  It works correctly for the first time it is called after the leaderboard variable is given data, but after that, the first leaderboard value remains shown on the phone, even though the debugger proves that the actual value has changed - and through use of breakpoints, I've also discovered that despite clearing the WebView in two separate ways at the start of each iteration, that doesn't work either.

Moreover, after running through the entire competition (that is, when the if statement resolves to false because step has grown too large), it again works once - the WebView is cleared as I had expected, and moreover if I change the value of step at runtime using another piece of code after finishing the iterations, I get the correct leaderboard displayed for that value of step (which then subsequently 'sticks' until I again reach the end and it gets cleared again.)

If anyone has any ideas why this might be happening, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the webview after the update. By the way, this update could be done calling javascript from java using a webclient.

Comment: @Juan I had not previously, though including it has not made any difference.